# How to package XML with runnable Jar?

Tags: eclipse, jar, path, testng, java-io

I have a Java project with many testNG classes. In order to call the suite of test classes you need to run an XML file. I wrote a class in the same package as the XML which runs said XML. I'm exporting the project as a runnable jar that uses the main as the launch configuration.

```
public class mainTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
       TestNG testng = new TestNG();
       List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();      
       File file = new File("src\\xml\\whole.xml");     
       suites.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
       testng.setTestSuites(suites);
       testng.run();    
   }
}
```

My export steps:

- Right click and export on the entire project
- Select Runnable JAR File
- Select "mainTest" as my launch configuration Export to Desktop

When I run this class directly in Eclipse, the XML is called fine. However, when I export the entire project as a runnable jar, I get this error. [image]

It seems the jar is looking for the XML in the same directory as the jar (where it doesn't exist), but shouldn't the XML already be included inside the jar?

Comment: If it wants *file* names, you're basically stuck keeping it out of the jar.

Comment: Can you explain why? From my understanding a jar is just a runnable "zip" folder so shouldn't it package everything under my project along with their appropriate folders and names?

Comment: Yes, but **TestNG** is looking for XML **file** names. The resources in a JAR would be accessed differently.

Comment: That's unfortunate :( Guess I'll have to bundle the XML separately. Is there any other way to get things to work in just one comprehensive file?